# Passing an integer value through a node attribute in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am new to chef. Please let me know how can I pass an integer value as a node attribute (chef-client -j).

Tried with json input, but I was not able to convert the hash value into an integer.
For example : If I am passing my -j  count:"1" , I need to the output node['count'] in integer value and not in hash.

Can someone help me in converting it into integer value in Chef or is there any other way I can send my integer input to the chef?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can provide any (primitive) node attribute in the chef-client execution using the `--json-attribute`, just make sure that the json you provide is a valid json file or a valid json string.

try this:

```sh
$ chef-client -j '{"count": 1}'
```