# Is there a way set chef attribute using environment variables?

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to do the following with no success

```
default['foo']['bar'] = ENV['baz']
```

It is resolving to empty, even though I have set up the environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

ruby native code which is not wrapped with chef resource, such as [`ruby_block`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html), will be executed in the compilation phase of chef-client run, and i think this is not your intention.

note that when you use an environment variable, you will need to set it on the converged node.

i would strongly recommend you not to use an environment variable, but to switch to node attribute, which can be set using the [`--json-attributes`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#options) option for chef-client. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56073181/1184717) for an example.